# Reactjs: How to save to var the result obtained from .then

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I save the data obtained from .then

Example:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
//Función que conecta un componente a Redux store.
import { connect } from "react-redux";



  class PruebasAPI extends Component {
    state = {
      Obtenerdata: [],
    };



    GetPriceCurrencie = () => {

      const CoinbasePro = require('coinbase-pro');
      const publicClient = new CoinbasePro.PublicClient();
      //publicClient.getProductTicker(sobre).then(response=> alert(response.price))
      publicClient.getProductTicker('ETH-EUR').then(output => {
          this.setState({
            Obtenerdata: output
          });

      } 
    )
    console.log("test123:", this.Obtenerdata )
    return this.Obtenerdata;

    };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.GetPriceCurrencie();

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
      if (newProps.token) {
        this.GetPriceCurrencie();      
      }
    }





  render() {

    console.log("Value is:", this.Obtenerdata )




      return (
        <Fragment>
          TEST 1
          <br></br>


        <div>
          <br></br>
          Test result: {this.Obtenerdata}

        </div>
        </Fragment>

    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    token: state.token
  };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PruebasAPI);
```

The error seen on console.log("test123:", this.Obtenerdata ) is undefined.

If i uncoment the line:
//publicClient.getProductTicker(sobre).then(response=> alert(response.price))

I have the number obtained: xxx.xx

How to save the response to a var ?

Thank you.

Comment: `this.Obtenerdata` should not be `this.state.Obtenerdata` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    state = {
      Obtenerdata: [],
    };
```

`Obtenerdata` is in your component's state object

So you need to do `this.state.Obtenerdata` instead of `this.Obtenerdata`

Answer (score 1):

you can storage in a state using `.then(response => this.setState({ Obtenerdata: response});` anda get data using this.state.Obtenerdata

Comment: This  one is also OK. thks.